# Inserting data after checking if table is empty

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database, executescalar

I have a server program that will store certain data sent by the client. One data is the client's hostname. The server will check if the hostname exist, if not then it will insert that new data. It should look like this.

```
hostname_id | hostname
------------------------
      1     | Admin
      2     | Guest_PC
      3     | Bob_PC2
```

My problem is it won't store the newly inserted data. It keeps on returning zero but not storing anything. Here is my code.(Edited to correct version)

```
string constring = "Database=chtbuster;Data Source=localhost;User Id=root;Password=''";
    string count1 = "SELECT COUNT(hostName) FROM chtbuster.hostnametable WHERE hostName=@machineName ";
    using (MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring))
    {
            MySqlCommand cmd1Database = new MySqlCommand(count1, conDataBase);
            conDataBase.Open();

             long count = (long)cmd1Database.ExecuteScalar();
             if (count == 0)
             {
                  string insert_ht = "INSERT INTO chtbuster.hostnametable(hostName) VALUES(@machineName);";
                  MySqlCommand cmd5Database = new MySqlCommand(insert_ht, conDataBase);

                  cmd5Database.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machineName", machineName);
                  cmd5Database.ExecuteNonQuery();
                  //*test* output.Text += "\n Empty " + count;
             }
             else
             {
                  //not empty, insert other data
             }

}
```

I have coded PHP database before and is new to C# database, I'm quite confused. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to _execute_ the SQL insert command you created....DOH!

Comment: @SteveWellens sir I am new to C# database. Is it the ExecuteNonQuery();?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one step with EXISTS:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT hostName FROM chtbuster.hostnametable WHERE hostName=@machineName)
  INSERT INTO chtbuster.hostnametable(hostName_id) VALUES(@machineName);
```

As mentioned in the comments, you need to execute the query to get a result.

Comment: sir? is it okay to ask if how should i output a selected query?
 string gethostname_id = "SELECT INTO chtbuster.hostnametable(hostName_id) WHERE hostName=@machineName";

Comment: The query, in my answer, doesn't return a value.  When executing, if you want to return a value, you would ExecuteScalar (like you did above), or ExecuteReader to return a data reader that includes any query results.

Comment: If you want to encapsulate your logic and return something meaningful, maybe write a stored procedure in the db.  Then, you logic isn't hard-coded in some sql in your application.

Comment: "encapsulate your logic" i do not know much about encapsulation but i will try ExecuteReader. Thanks.